# How to child a Plane?

Tags: javascript, three.js, plane

I have a plane:

```
 let = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
```

I want to rotate the plane based on a parent object's movement. It doesn't seem like I can do:

```
parentObj.add(plane);
```

so what's the next simplest method of achieving this? Would be great if I didn't have to manually set its position. I need to use [Plane](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Plane) specifically for its `clippingPlanes` feature.

I guess I could create an Object3d mesh as a "plane", make it a child of `parentObj`, then set the Plane to the Object3d's position every update? Is there a less convoluted method I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't seem like I can do: parentObj.add(plane);

No, that's not possible. An instance of `THREE.Plane` is a pure mathematical representation of a plane. Hence, it is not derived from `THREE.Object3D` and thus can't be part of the scene graph.

That means you have to compute the plane per animation step (considering it is not static but moves around in 3D space).

`three.js R110`